# Как задать скорость и направление движения фона нажатием мыши?

Tags: javascript

Почему скорость у бг с каждым нажатием становится все больше и больше?

Мне нужно чтобы фон двигался со скоростью, которая будет задаваться положением клика и меняться после каждого последующего, ну и направление должно зависеть от клика

вот пример как это работает сейчас:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fl2UYJzu2PaFD1CIrm-ed_yFXlY5putR/view?usp=share_link

А вот как выглядит код:

задал начальную позицию для бг

```js
function flight() {
    let wmap = document.querySelector('#wmap');
    let pos1 = wmap.clientWidth;
    let pos2 = wmap.clientHeight + 800;

    wmap.style.backgroundPositionX = `${pos1}px`;
    wmap.style.backgroundPositionY = `${pos2}px`;

    let v, v1;
    let x0, y0;
```

задал центр дива чтобы определять скорость по расстояние от центра до точки нажатия, чем ближе к краю нажатие, тем быстрее будет перемещаться фон

```js
 wmap.addEventListener('mouseover', takeOff);

    function takeOff(e) {
        console.log(e.offsetX);
        x0 = 350;
        y0 = 350;

    }
```

определил скорость и направление, заставил двигаться

```js
 wmap.addEventListener('mousedown',move);

     function move(e) {
       if(v != undefined) clearInterval(movement);
        
        console.log(e);
        v = -(e.offsetX - x0);
        v1 = -(e.offsetY - y0);
        console.log(v, v1);
        let movement = setInterval(moveBg, 20);
       
        // requestAnimationFrame(moveBg);
        // moveBg();
    }
    function moveBg() {
        pos1 += v * 0.01;
        pos2 += v1 * 0.01;
        wmap.style.backgroundPositionX = `${pos1}px`;
        wmap.style.backgroundPositionY = `${pos2}px`;
    }
}
flight();
```

А еще интересно как сюда вставить requestAnimationFrame вместо setInterval и можно ли заменить background-position на transform-translate?

Comment: `setInterval` - нигде не останавливается. на каждый `move` создается новый интервал

Comment: @Grundy clearInterval, но куда его добавить? или что-то другое?

Comment: его нужно добавить в то место - где интервал должен заканчиваться

Comment: @Grundy при новом клике старый должен заканчиваться и начинаться новый, то есть добавлять в функцию move, добавил вот такую строчку в начало

if(v != undefined) clearInterval(movement);
, но тогда выходит так что клик срабатывает только 1 раз, потом я не могу менять скорость и направление.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный код фукнции move, что бы было понятно, куда вы вставили clearInterval и как + movement это должен быть id интервала

Comment: @SwaD отредактировал

Comment: `let movement` Вынесете за пределы функции. Внутри функции сохраняйте туда id интервала `movement = setInterval(moveBg, 20);`. А ваш if не нужен, просто всегда останавливайте интервал

Comment: @SwaD в такой ситуации начиная со 2 нажатия появляется ошибка, так как не объявлен movement, объявил его в самом начале без значения и теперь все работает как я хотел

Comment: @SwaD а ну вы уже написали) Спасибо)

Comment: @SwaD но вопрос в конце все еще актуален. Не подскажете случаем? Буду очень рад узнать)

Comment: @SwaD, если интервал останавливать всегда - то интервал - не нужен, хватит таймаута

Comment: @Спиридон с этим не работал, не подскажу

Comment: @Grundy Как я понимаю, надо что бы как раз был интервал, иначе придется таймаут пускать друг за другом. Под всегда имелось ввиду - каждый вызов функции move останавливает предыдущий интервал, что то там считает и запускает новый

Comment: @SwaD. _таймаут пускать друг за другом_ - именно так. С интервалом происходит тоже самое, просто setTimeout рассчитан на то что он о\ин раз срабатывает, а интервал рассчитан  на многократное срабатывание, а тут прерывается после первого же

Comment: @Grundy Обрати внимание, интервал останавливается и запускается в функции move, а сам интервал дергает постоянно фукнцию move**Bg**. Так что остановки интервала, сразу после первого срабатывания не будет.

Comment: @SwaD, учитывая как и когда срабатывает `move` - будет. (в большинстве случаев)